# i am unable to change profile pic in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I created a profile form in models.py for and form.py to update it but all thing got updated except profile picture
[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrOwo.png)

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your profile updated.")
        else:
            status_code = 400
            message = 'Please correct the error below.'
            messages.error(request, "Please use correct information")
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

[forms.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2snCr.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LBve.png)

Comment: try using forward slash at the end of upload_to path like this: upload_to='profile_pics/'

Comment: Please include actual code in your question not just images of code. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, you need to include `request.FILES` where you initialize your **form** in the `POST` request like this:

```
profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
```

Then in your **html** you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your **form**:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: i can change it from admin panel but unable to change from profile form don't know why

Comment: add your form to the question

Comment: added forms.py please have a look and if there is any error please suggest

Comment: does the form save the image and you can see it in admin or are you just unable to see it after submitting?

Comment: i can only update profile pic from admin panel but when i trying to update it from profile form except profile pic everything got updated

Comment: first of remove the `/` slash from your `upload_to` attribute in the image field and tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0):

try using forward slash at the end of `upload_to` path like this: `upload_to='profile_pics/'`